# Can I show pdf output inside the RStudio viewer pane?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

If I knit my document, I get the pdf output in the RStudio: View PDF window, which usually pops up or refreshes on command.

Is it possible for this viewer to be located inside RStudio, in the bottom right pane, for example?

Answer (score 2):

Just change your output to html_document instead of pdf_document and then change it back to pdf when you are finished.  That's what @J_F is doing but forgot to mention it.

Comment: This should be a comment .. It's a neat trick, but isn't always possible

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, you just have to change on thing in RStudio: Change to "Preview in Viewer Pane"

[image]

Comment: Doing this still makes it output the pdf in a separate window. I searched around and believe that viewing the pdf directly in a viewer pane is not an option. Not a big deal, but someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Only works for Quarto (`.qmd`) so far, see https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/7129#issuecomment-1252365925